# How to retrieve record in group by with join table depend on MAX?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

This my query in model:

```
return $this->db->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_customer.cus_code = tbl_cus_account.custcode')
                ->where("status", 1)
                ->where("DATE_FORMAT(nextbillingdate,'%Y-%m') <= ", date('Y-m'))
                ->select('*,MAX(issuewithmain) AS issuewithmain, SUM(monthlyfee) AS monthlyfee, count(accountcode) as rows')
                ->group_by('custcode')
                ->get('tbl_cus_account');
```

- The below are my table for join query:
  [image]
  [image]

-The result I want as the image below:
[image]

Comment: whats the result that shows after execute your model query ?

Comment: hello Naveen! The result always show for the first row, it mean it show for row accountcode 4

Comment: The `tbl_customer` will have multiple `tbl_cus_account`?

Comment: Yes, tbl_customer has many tbl_cus_account. It mean one to many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be something like this

```
SELECT t.*, t2.rows, t2.monthlyfee from tbl_cus_account t join (SELECT MAX(issuewithmain) AS issuewithmain, custcode, count(accountcode) as rows, SUM(monthlyfee) AS monthlyfee from tbl_cus_account JOIN tbl_customer ON tbl_customer.cus_code = tbl_cus_account.custcode  where status = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(nextbillingdate,"%Y-%m") <= DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%Y-%m") GROUP BY custcode) t2 on t.issuewithmain = t2.issuewithmain and t.custcode = t2.custcode
```

Here you made an extra join to the same table, to only get the exactly records that match with your `max(issuewithmain)`

You need to transform this query to codeigniter and add the conditions of the where to the corresponding table.

Maybe something like this, I haven't test it

UPDATE

```
return $this->db->join('(SELECT MAX(issuewithmain) AS issuewithmain, custcode, count(accountcode) as rows, SUM(monthlyfee) AS monthlyfee from tbl_cus_account where status = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(nextbillingdate,"%Y-%m") <= "'.date('Y-m').'" GROUP BY custcode) t2', 'tbl_cus_account.issuewithmain = t2.issuewithmain AND t2.custcode = tbl_cus_account.custcode')->select('tbl_cus_account.*, t2.monthlyfee, t2.rows') ->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_customer.cus_code = t2.custcode') ->group_by('t2.custcode') ->get('tbl_cus_account');
```

Comment: it has error with join table of customer with tbl_cus_account ->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_customer.cus_code = tbl_cus_account.custcode') and sum monthlyfee is not right of amount

Comment: I updated my anser, now the join with tbl_customer is inside the new join. The error with the join tbl_customer has to be because of a error on a name with the columns relation if you let me know the correct names I will change it.

Comment: Nerea, it still error as the same of join table. And the key relation of these two are tbl_customer(cus_code) and tbl_cus_account(custcode)

Comment: Hi Nerea! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: return $this->db->join('(SELECT MAX(issuewithmain) AS issuewithmain, custcode, count(accountcode) as rows, SUM(monthlyfee) AS monthlyfee from tbl_cus_account where status = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(nextbillingdate,"%Y-%m") <= "'.date('Y-m').'" GROUP BY custcode) t2', 'tbl_cus_account.issuewithmain = t2.issuewithmain AND  t2.custcode = tbl_cus_account.custcode')
                //->select('tbl_cus_account.*, t2.monthlyfee, t2.rows')
                ->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_customer.cus_code = t2.custcode')
                ->group_by('t2.custcode')
                ->get('tbl_cus_account');

Comment: pls update your answer and i will click right for you.